# Help deciphering breaker box diagram (where can tandem breakers be installed?)

Tags: electrical

I'm doing some research ahead of a tankless water heater installation, and wanted to check which breaker slots will take tandem breakers. (I won't be doing the install myself).

I *think* it's telling me that every slot will take a tandem breaker. However the diagram doesn't match the real life layout (there's actually 10 slots per side), and the text is a little cryptic & confusing.

**Can anyone help decipher the text & diagrams to confirm where tandem breakers can be installed?**

[image: breaker box label]

[image: breaker box label]

Comment: Keep in mind that a tankless water heater uses a lot of power, so therefore likely 240V, which means two breakers next to each other **but on opposite legs**. Which means, in most cases, **not tandem**. That doesn't mean tandem is useless - but it means you may have to move other stuff to tandem in order to free up **spaces**. For example, if you are full right now then you might move a pair of 15A independent breakers and a pair of 20A independent breakers into a tandem 2x15 and a tandem 2x20 in order to get to 2 **full spaces** next to each other available for your water heater.

Comment: Remember to watch bus stab limits with tandem breakers. I don't see their bus stab figure but it's usually 125A.  That means the breaker *space* on the left and the right, *inclusive of both breakers in the tandem*, cannot total more than 125A.   If you have a tandem 20 on the left, and a 100A to the right, that's 140A and that's a no-go.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact thanks for the reminder, I think some shuffling around will be needed. I did discovered these "quadplex" breakers which offer two 240v circuits but only use two spaces which seem helpful (for example https://www.homedepot.com/p/Siemens-Two-40-Amp-Double-Pole-Type-QT-Quad-Circuit-Breaker-Q24040CT2/206632164)

But it sounds like I'll have to take into account what Harper-ReinstateMonica points out too (i.e. vertically offsetting the heavyweight breakers).

Answer (score 3):

It is telling you that each slot will take a tandem breaker. The lightning bolt like line through the layout is just a way of communicating a repeating pattern in limited space.

Comment: Thanks @Reid, I was wondering what that meant. (I thought "this is electrified" was too obvious a thing for them to label!).

Answer (score 3):

It means all spaces can take tandem breakers.

To confirm I would continue looking at labels in the panel for a catalog number, judging by the size of the main lug kit it will look something like HOM2040M200PC. If you go to Homedepot's website you can see that now a standard format for Homeline catalog numbers shows the "2040" portion of the number is 20 spaces, 40 circuits, meaning all spaces can take tandems. You could also go to the Schneider (Square D) website and download the [Datasheet](https://www.se.com/us/en/product/download-pdf/HOM2040M200PC) for the panel.